# Infimum proof, with function

Tags: calculus, functions, supremum-and-infimum

I have this question here:

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $m \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the set:

$A = \{x \in [a,b) \mid f(x) > m\}$,  $A$ is not empty.

Prove that $s=\inf(A)$ exists and that $a\leq s<b$.

Can I say that $A$ is bounded from below by $a$? What is the explanation for that? Is this because $a\leq x<b$? But what about $f(x)$?

From here, should I use $\varepsilon$ somehow?

Thank you for your help and for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your set $A$ is, by definition, a subset of $[a,b)$. So, $a$ is a lower bound of $A$ and therefore, since $\inf A$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$, $a\leqslant\inf A$.

And there is some $c\in A$. Since $c\in[a,b)$, $c<b$. So, $\inf A\leqslant c<b$.

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't thought of the $c \in A$ thing! Can you please explain me your thinking method of how you came up to find $c$? So in the next questions that I have I will try to think the same way you did. :)

Comment: All I did was to think that $\inf A$ is smaller than or equal to any element of $A$ and that $A$ must have some element $c$. So, $c<b$.

Comment: Thank you! So A must have some element c, because by definition of $A$ not empty, even if $A$ has only one element, it will be equal or greater to $a$, and smaller to $b$, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $a$ is a lower bound of $A$ (i.e. $a\leq x$ for all $x\in A$) we need to show that it is indeed the *greatest* lower bound of $A$  (this is the definition of an infimum). Suppose for contradiction there exists an element $c>a$ that is also a lower bound of $A$. But $a\in A$ and by assumption $a<c$, hence $c$ can’t be a lower bound on $A$. Therefore $\inf(A)$ exists, namely $a$.

Next we need to show that $a\leq a < b$. Clearly this boils down to showing that $a<b$. Note that $b$ is an upper bound of $A$ and also $b\notin A$. This implies $x<b$ for all $x\in A$. In particular, $a<b$, as required.

Comment: Vey nice!! Loved the way you did it! Thank you for your explanation! :)

Comment: @Math4me no problem. Feel free to accept whichever answer you find most helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @ChubbyChef It seems that the OP didn't find any of our answers useful.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos this is why I feel moderators should be able to "force accept" answers in select situations. Otherwise questions like these just bloat the unsolved percentage.